# Why the data is undefined express post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is a part from my code , I have used json.parser and everything needed to parse the data to be able for read , but I still get undefined and an empty return result {} when I use postman.

note : the following code working fine on local host but at server I have the problem.

```
app.use(bodyparser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyparser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyparser.text());


router.post('/',(req, res) => {
    //if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    insert(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

the insert method :

```
function insert(sicker) {
    var person = sicker;

    const schema = joi.object().keys({
        ID: joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        Blod: joi.string().required(),
        Allergic: joi.string(),
        Chronic: joi.string(),
    });
    // validate data
    if (joi.validate(person, schema)) {
        con.connect();
        con.query('INSERT INTO `sick`(`ID`, `Blod`, `Allergic`, `Chronic`) VALUES ("' + person.ID + '","' + person.Blod + '","' + person.Allergic + '","' + person.Chronic + '")', function(err, rows, fields) {

            if (err) { console.log(err) }
        })
    } else {}
    //ID + Blod + allergic + chronic +
    con.end()
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that your remote server is able to talk to the database? i.e. does your GET work with querying data?

Comment: thanks for reply , yes it s working on get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was at using the postamn for test instead of using Test I should use Body => raw => json and then create the body and post data , I hope it helps someone elese.